# Are allergic reactions to detergents and fabric softener localized or generalized?

Tags: dermatology, allergy, allergen

When people have allergic reactions to washing machine detergents or dryer fabric softener sheets, are the reactions typically "all over" the contact area, or can they be localized to very specific areas.

For example, would you expect the reaction to be all over the abdomen and chest, or could it just be on a small area of the chest or abdomen?

Comment: Have you looked into "local vs systemic allergic reactions" or " Systemic contact dermatitis ?" Editing your question with a little more research may elicit an answer.